# BONDI API to launch SMS app

Tags: bada

Is it possible for widget to launch SMS app (via BONDI API) on SamSung wave device, so that the pre-defined content can be included ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AND It is not possible to launch SMS app with pre-defined SMS content"
Old question, i know, but it IS possible. See 'SmsCamera' app, you write content in application and then send it to SMS app..

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

With BONDI API 1.01 (not 1.1), it is not possible to send SMS directly (without launching native SMS application)

AND It is not possible to launch SMS app with pre-defined SMS content